# C code loop optimisation (without compiler optimisation)

Tags: performance, c

What manual code optimizations could I apply to this code to make it run faster in an environment where compiler optimizations are not desired (compiled with -o flag)? Arrays are size 512x512.

```
for(iy=0;iy<Ny;iy++) {
for(ix=0;ix<Nx;ix++) {

if (ix==0) {
  pudx = (u[1][iy] + u[Nx-1][iy] - 2.0*u[0][iy])/(calc1);   
} else if (ix==Nx-1) {
  pudx = (u[0][iy] + u[Nx-2][iy] - 2.0*u[Nx-1][iy])/(calc1);  
} else {
  pudx = (u[ix+1][iy] + u[ix-1][iy] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])/(calc1);
}

if (iy==0) {
  pudy = (u[ix][1] + u[ix][Ny-1] - 2.0*u[ix][0])/(calc2);    
} else if (iy==Ny-1) {
  pudy = (u[ix][0] + u[ix][Ny-2] - 2.0*u[ix][Ny-1])/(calc2);   
} else {
  pudy = (u[ix][iy+1] + u[ix][iy-1] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])/(calc2);
}


u_new[ix][iy] = 2.0*u[ix][iy] - u_old[ix][iy] + calc*(pudx+pudy);

  }
}
```

So far I can think to take the inverse of `calc1` and `calc2` outside the loop.

I am now trying to find a way to write the if statements outside the loop but cannot find a way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your title is too common a request to be appropriate for this site. What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question. Please read [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is the data type stored in the array? Also, are Nx and Ny constants? Or just constant-during-the-function?

Comment: Nx and Ny are constants. Doubles are stored in the array.

Comment: "Any suggestions?" --> post compilable code, and sample input along with optimization goals.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. It should be possible to just copy and paste it to get a working program. Even if you only present a code snippet, the opening and closing braces must be balanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to move as much as possible out of the inner loops. This seems pretty easy. Also, spaces are free and don't slow your program down at all (long variable names slow your code way down, but spaces don't)!

Your inner loop is `ix`. You have a series of `if/elsif/else` that checks the value of `ix` **but** the interesting cases are the first and last iterations of that loop! So, shorten the loop and move the exceptional cases outside of it. Of course, you can do the same thing with the `if/elsif/else` centered on the `iy` variable, moving those statements out of the outer loop. But that would make copies of the inner loop twice, which you probably don't want to do. So maybe settle for a little less and move the computations out to the outer loop:

```
for (prev_iy = Ny - 1, iy = 0, next_iy = 1; 
     iy < Ny; 
     prev_iy = iy, ++iy, ++next_iy) 
{
    if (iy == Ny - 1) 
        next_iy = 0;

    /* if (ix == 0) {  -- moved out of inner loop */
    ix = 0; 

    pudx = (u[ix+1][iy] + u[Nx-1][iy] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])/(calc1);   
    pudy = (u[ix][next_iy] + u[ix][prev_iy] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])/(calc2);
    u_new[ix][iy] = 2.0 * u[ix][iy] - u_old[ix][iy] + calc * (pudx + pudy);

    for (ix = 1; ix < Nx - 1; ++ix) {
        pudx = (u[ix+1][iy] + u[ix-1][iy] - 2.0 * u[ix][iy])/(calc1);
        pudy = (u[ix][next_iy] + u[ix][prev_iy] - 2.0 * u[ix][iy])/(calc2);
        u_new[ix][iy] = 2.0*u[ix][iy] - u_old[ix][iy] + calc*(pudx+pudy);
    }

    /* if (ix == Nx - 1) { -- moved out of inner loop */
    pudx = (u[0][iy] + u[ix-1][iy] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])/(calc1);  
    pudy = (u[ix][next_iy] + u[ix][prev_iy] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])/(calc2);
    u_new[ix][iy] = 2.0*u[ix][iy] - u_old[ix][iy] + calc*(pudx+pudy);
}
```

Next, I would suggest inverting the loops (loop on ix, then iy). Or swap the names of the x/y variables. I don't know what your target architecture is, but in general C compilers store data in [*row major* order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) and it can make a huge difference to performance if you comply with that ordering. Obviously, you're going to access all the cells, but you really want to access the sells from low to high memory address as much as possible.

If your `Nx` and `Ny` values truly are constants - you indicate the matrix is 512 x 512 - you can get a lot of good benefit by doing a bitwise `&` with 511. For example "-1" will become 511, 512 will become 0. So long as your array sizes are always a power of 2, a bitwise and is cheap and will let you collapse all your cases into a single line of code.

There are several "repeated" values. You can probably cache those values profitably. (For example, `u[ix][iy]` gets used a lot.)

Even better, keep in mind that `u[ix-1][iy]` is the same as `u[ix][iy]` the last time through the loop. So you can "save" those values from one loop cycle to the next and use them in different places. Similarly, `u[ix+1][iy]` in one loop will be `u[ix][iy]` when ix gets one higher, so you can save that value as well.

For your inner loop, you really have three values in a pipeline, call them *last, curr,* and *next.* The `next` value is `u[ix+1][iy]`. The `last` and `curr` values are simply older copies of `next`:

```
last = curr;
curr = next;
next = u[ix + 1][iy];
pudx = (-2.0 * curr + last + next) / calc1;
```

You similarly have 3 values in a pipeline going perpindicular: [iy-1], [iy], and [iy+1]. Obviously `curr` is the same for both, but I don't think you can effectively cache your previous 512 values. (The CPU cache might store them, but you shouldn't try to cache them in your program.)

**Pointers?**

Because your computations are fairly straightforward, one thing you might consider doing is using pointers instead of array accesses. Again, this assumes that you refactor your loops to be in the right order. For example, you might try something like:

```
prev_row = u[511];
this_row = u[0] + 1;
next_row = u[1];
new = u_new;
old = u_old;

for (i = 0; i < 511 * 512; ++i) {
    last = curr;
    curr = next;
    curr2 = 2.0 * curr;
    next = *this_row++;
    pudy = (*prev_row++ + *next_row++ - curr2) / calc1;
    pudx = (last + next - curr2) / calc2;

    *new++ = curr2 - *old++ + calc * (pudx + pudy);
}

/* Now handle last row, after fixing next_row pointer */

next_row = u[0];
for (i = 0; i < 512; ++i ) {
    ... as above ...
}
```

It's worth pointing out that right now your code is very fragile. You have a lot of array indexing, and any little mistake (like a plus sign instead of a minus sign, or an x instead of a y) is going to give you a potentially valid-seeming result that won't be quite right.

You will need a strong set of test cases to catch this sort of thing. But I'd also recommend that you use variables or preprocessor macros to **spell out** things instead of expressing them symbolically.

For example:

```
#define ABOVE(m,row,col)  (m[(row)-1][col])
#define BELOW(m,row,col)  (m[(row)+1][col])
#define LEFT(m,row,col)   (m[row][(col)-1])
#define RIGHT(m,row,col)  (m[row][(col)+1])
#define CENTER(m,row,col) (m[row][col])
```

Then you can say:

```
pudx = (BELOW(u,ix,iy) + ABOVE(u,ix,iy) - 2.0 * CENTER(u,ix,iy)) / (calc1);
```

You can take this farther, but the idea is to produce a single source of truth that you can stare at REALLY HARD to confirm it is correct, and then have everything else look basically the same.

This doesn't apply to the pointer scenario, obviously. But in that case you will probably want to define a macro for the loop body, so you can repeat it easily.

**Assembly**

Your compiler has a command-line switch that will produce assembly code as output. It might be `-S` (gcc) or `/FAs` (msvc), but it's there. Use it! If you're not going to enable optimization, then you are going to have to measure the effects for yourself. One good way to do that is to look at the generated assembly and see what result a particular change produces.

Honestly, this is difficult. But if you focus yourself down to a small section of the code - the innermost loop - you can generally figure out what is going on. And for the most part, shorter is better.

**Optimization**

You don't say why optimization options are not available to you. Unless this is for some class assignment, I'd encourage you to try enabling optimization anyway. One thing you might do is *split your code*. Move this one function into a separate `.c` source file, and get it to compile and run okay. Then start building your project however you usually do, but configure this one separate `.c` file to use a higher optimization level. That might get you around whatever blockage (technical or political) you are encountering.

Of course, good unit tests are essential for this.